# Custom serialization for fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

Is there a way to have a custom serialization for fields in rails, a method that runs when a field is saved and loaded to convert from/to a string which is what ultimately is saved on the database.

Specifically what I want to do is have a field of type symbol like gender, with possible values :male and :female storing "male" and "female" on the database. There are some workarounds, like:

```
def gender
  read_attribute(:gender).try(:to_sym)
end
```

but that leaves obj.attributes unchanged, so it's a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it in Rails 3.1. The object you want to serialize has to reply to `load` and `dump` methods.

Here is an example of serializing a string in Base64.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  class Base64
    def load(text)
      return unless text
      text.unpack('m').first
    end

    def dump(text)
      [text].pack 'm'
    end
  end

  serialize :bank_account_number, Base64.new
end
```

For more details see: http://archives.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2011/03/09/custom-activerecord-attribute-serialization/index.html

Comment: The details link appears to be dead now, unfortunately. Was there a reason why you defined `dump` and `load` as instance methods, and pass a new instance into `serialize`? As opposed to defining them as class methods and passing the class into `serialize`? Just trying to understand, thanks!

Comment: I'm taking a wild shot in the dark here, but it looks as if ActiveRecord serialization will use any object that responds to `:dump` and `:load`. So, no. There is no reason why these are instance methods as opposed to class methods.

Answer (score 4):

```
def whachamacallit
  read_attribute("whachamacallit").to_sym
end
def whachamacallit=(name)
  write_attribute("whachamacallit", name.to_s)
end
```

store them as stings in the database, but extract them as symbols when you pull them out then convert back before you save.
 would work with any number or combination of strings / symbols.

to limit it to only a select few

```
validates_inclusion_of :whachamacallit, :in => [ :male, :female, :unknown, :hidden ]
```

Comment: I've considered this solution, what I don't like about it is that if I look at obj.attributes the field is obviously a string instead of a field and I know it'll come back to bit me when I less expect it.

Answer (score 3):

From http://blog.quov.is/2012/05/01/custom-activerecord-attribute-serializers/

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :ingredients, IngredientsList
end

class IngredientsList < Array
  def self.dump(ingredients)
    ingredients ? ingredients.join("\n") : nil
  end

  def self.load(ingredients)
    ingredients ? new(ingredients.split("\n")) : nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define the models to_xml for a model and it will do that 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html

its possible to define Marshall.dump and put in that way i think, but its something to look into

Comment: I'm not talking about serializing a whole model to a string, but serializing a single field to a string to store in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `serialize` method inside the model. Please reference to this link:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html
(ps. search keyword "serialize" in that page ;D)

In short, you could do this:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :db_field
end
```

Rails would automatically serialize the field before saving to database, and deserialize it after fetched from the database.

Comment: The problem with that is that it converts to yaml, making the data harder to use in queries when just saving a straight symbol to string conversion would be fine. That's what I've meant by saving "male" and "female" in the database, that is, instead of "--- :male" and "--- :female").

Answer (score 0):

well for just male/female you could just do a Boolean column like male and if it was false assume that meant female, add wrapper methods for it

```
def female? 
  return !self.male?
end
```

Comment: This is just an example, I want to store more than two symbols. Try it with male, female, unknown and hidden.

Answer (score 0):

We just released a gem ([AttributeHelpers](https://github.com/panorama-ed/attribute_helpers)) that does exactly this. Disclaimer: I am a maintainer for the gem.

It allows you to call `attr_symbol :gender` in your class definition and the serialization happens automagically.