# Postgresql JSON column as HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby, json, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table called 'my_models' with a 'json' column called 'settings'.

I also have the following model:

```
class MyModels < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The 'settings' attribute of an 'MyModels' instance is a Hash.

Is it possible to configure 'MyModels' to type cast the raw column value of 'settings' to a HashWithIndifferentAccess instead of Hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Serialize alone wont work here since `HashWithIndifferentAccess` does not respond to both `load` and `dump` methods, but you can do this:

```
class THEModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_hash_attribute
    read_attribute(:my_hash_attribute).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```

See also [Custom serialization for fields in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472479/custom-serialization-for-fields-in-rails)

Comment: Ahh a custom serializer. I always thought their were limited to text columns, but it works great!

Comment: While this works, it should probably be noted that it prevents you from editing the hash directly. For example:

    model.my_hash_attribute = {}
    model.my_hash_attribute[:test] = "abc" 
    model.my_hash_attribute # {}

Doesn't work like most people would expect it to.

Comment: with a cursory look at HashWithIndifferentAccess, I can't figure out *why* calling `.with_indifferent_access` on a jsonb attribute breaks writing to it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28683140/3453300 for an answer which allows modifying the hash.