# Is there a way to serialize ActiveRecord's JSON properties using HashWithIndifferentAccess?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I am using `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` in a Rails application.  Suppose I have a schema:

```
  create_table "foo", id: :bigserial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.jsonb    "data",              null: false
  end
```

Now suppose I run the following code:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = :foo
end

my_foo = Foo.create!(:name => 'foobar', :data => {:a => 'hello'})
my_foo = Foo.where(:name => 'foobar').first!
puts my_foo.data[:a]
puts my_foo.data['a']
```

The output would be:

```
# nil
# 'hello'
```

Is it possible to ask ActiveRecord to automatically deserialize jsonb types using HashWithIndifferentAccess?

Comment: `def data; HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(super); end` is a workaround if nothing better comes along.

Comment: @muistooshort another way to put it is `super.with_indifferent_access`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

| You can use a custom serializer so you can access the JSON object with symbols as well.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, HashSerializer
end

# app/serializers/hash_serializer.rb
class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash
  end

  def self.load(hash)
    (hash || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```

Full credit - sans googling - goes to http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails.

Comment: To get this working in Rails 5 I removed the `#to_json` call on `hash` in `.dump`.

Comment: Thanks @JoeMasilotti!

Comment: for future googlers: you can also add an explicit `#as_json` call on `hash` in `.dump`, to be a bit more explicit

Answer (score 6):

If your root object is an array you need to handle it slightly differently.

**Rails 5+**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, HashSerializer
  serialize :some_list, ArrayHashSerializer
end

class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash
  end

  def self.load(hash)
    (hash || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end

class ArrayHashSerializer
  def self.dump(array)
    array
  end

  def self.load(array)
    (array || []).map(&:with_indifferent_access)
  end
end
```

**Rails <= 4**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences, HashSerializer
  serialize :some_list, ArrayHashSerializer
end

class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.to_json
  end

  def self.load(hash)
    (hash || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end

class ArrayHashSerializer
  def self.dump(array)
    array.to_json
  end

  def self.load(array)
    (array || []).map(&:with_indifferent_access)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In rails 6 I was getting errors with some of these answers - notably the with_indifferent_access method.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
#in models/user.rb - role is a jsonb column
class User
    serialize :role, ApplicationHelper::JsonbIndifferentSerializer
end

#in helpers/application_helper.rb - probably not best practive to put it here
#but for a simple class I didn't want to add a whole folder under /app
class JsonbIndifferentSerializer
    def self.dump(obj)
      obj.to_json
    end
    def self.load(str_json)
      hsh = JSON.load(str_json) if str_json.class == String
      HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(hsh)
    end
end
```